# cp: ‘x’ and ‘y’ are the same file

Tags: cp

This is really weird. I am trying to copy a file. I do
`cp config.yaml config-test.yaml`. However, I get `cp: ‘config.yaml’ and ‘config-test.yaml’ are the same file`.

`ls -l config*.yaml` gives

`May 30 16:01 config-train.yaml
Jun  1 14:09 config.yaml`

`config-test.yaml` does not exist in the directory yet.

Never seen this before all this years using `cp`. Can any one tell me what's going on?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

when I do `ls -li config*.yaml` I get:

```
398985520 -rw-r--r-- 1 y91 user 3088 May 30 16:01 config-train.yaml
398985526 -rw-r--r-- 1 y91 user 3091 Jun  1 14:09 config.yaml
```

Note, I can't see `config-test.yaml`. However, when I do `ls -li config-test.yaml`, I get:

```
398985526 -rw-r--r-- 1 y91 user 3091 Jun  1 14:09 config-test.yaml
```

Why couldn't I see `config-test.yaml` when I simply did `ls -li config*.yaml`? Why do I have to explicitly list it?

Comment: Can we get a long directory listing of those files e.g. `ls -l config*.yaml`

Comment: 2 files with the same inode, one of them not visible when you enumerate the directory, but is visible when you explicitly try to `stat()` it. This smells like filesystem corruption.

Comment: `config-test.yaml` probably has some non-graphic characters in it. Try `ls -b`

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the output of `ls -li` for the two files you will probably notice that they are the same file (i.e. hard linked together).  You see this if the two files have the SAME inode number in the ls listing.  Thus, the reporting of the files being the same.